# how to know if a user has a certain cookie using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have been stuck on this problem for a couple hours now, and cant seem to get off of it. I have a html website where i'm giving a user a cookie called "schoolid" and it has the school's ID in it. If a user has a certain school ID, in this case "gms08",they will be redirected to another website. This is what i have so far in the cookie area.
I have a check cookie function checking to make sure the user has it, but i cant seem to get it to pick up on the fact that the user has the cookie and it is gms08.

[i.stack.imgur.com/wQjnx.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQjnx.png)

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Gfjc7iTG

```
<script>
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
</script>
<script>
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
</script>
<script>
function checkCookie() {
    var id = getCookie("schoolid");
    if (id != "") {
        alert("Welcome again ");
    } else {
    alert("user");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Paste the code and click CTRL + K. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Are you even calling your function `checkCookie()`?

Comment: Java is not JavaScript

Comment: When i call checkcookie, it says welcome again, meaning the cookie returned nothing.

Comment: `checkCookie` says "Welcome again", means `id != ""`, means the cookie did return something. Just `console.log(id)`